# How can we use machine learning to detect nude content in user-uploaded videos

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

How can I use `machine learning` to detect nude content in user-uploaded videos on my educational website forum?

I'm building an educational website forum where users can upload videos, but some users may upload nude content which is against our terms of use. We have created a report feature, but relying solely on it is not enough, as we expect more users. We need a system that can read user files before they are uploaded to our database. We want to use `computer-vision` to scan user files and return an error message if there is any nude content, preventing it from being uploaded to the database.

Comment: With opencv you can look frame-by-frame of a movie, and use object detection to look for patterns of nude people. It is of course not entirely failsafe (there will be movies that are marked, but are innocent, and others will pass the check).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what is `OpenCv frame-by-frame` ? and how can I use it to solve this problem?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124575/can-we-use-image-url-to-detect-video-content-in-django

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it is not, the second question was about how to do it perfectly, and the first question was about how to use a library to make that happen. So the second question isn't the same as the first question, but I deleted the second question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what type of AI can do this please?

Comment: A bit "off-topic", but maybe it can be useful to you or someone else in the future when tackling a similar problem. The primary question to ask would be: *How **probable** is it for a user to upload a public video with nude content?* You can make it clear how severe the consequences would be to do so, before letting someone upload a video or an admin can verify it before making it public. Implementation of Captcha and account creation requirement can help fight bots. A bit extreme, but you could also tie the account to a person's real identity, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use machine learning algorithms to solve these kind of problems. For your specific case you need to solve a classification problem. Since you need a quick solution, use a library to do the thing. Use [`nsfw-detector`](https://pypi.org/project/nsfw-detector/) to detect them.

Here is a code to read your video frame-by-frame and feed the classifier model. It checks the video every tenth frame.

```py
import cv2
from nsfw_detector import predict

model = predict.load_model('./nsfw_mobilenet2.224x224.h5')
thresh = 0.69

def is_image_nsfw(image_path):
    result = predict.classify(model, image_path)
    if result[image_path]['neutral'] < thresh:
        return True
    return False

def is_video_nsfw(video_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_num = 0
    is_nsfw = False
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        frame_num += 1
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            if frame_num % 10 == 0:
                result = predict.classify_nd(model, frame)
                if result['neutral'] < thresh:
                    # video is NSFW
                    is_nsfw = True
                    break
            
        # Break the loop
        else: 
            break
    cap.release()
    return is_nsfw
```

**Edit:**

In this method you will use a pre-trained model. You have to download the model file from this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ir_public/nsfwjscdn/nsfw_mobilenet2.224x224.h5) and put it where your code is. e.g. if your code file is `main.py`, you have to put this file exactly next to `main.py`.

Comment: you really should explore that library more (read the source). image files are not required. also: logic bugs in your code. you extract every tenth frame but infer on _every_ frame (ten times the same...).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your comment, you're right. I was sleepy when I wrote this answer :)) . I will fix it.

Comment: @AliEnt How can I use this 2 function in the function that are in my question. what do you meant by `image_path` and `video_path` that are in these two functions? Do you want me to add nude `images` and `Video` inside my `MEDIA_URL` ? You should create your code according to the way I provided my function in this question.

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. you have to define these functions in your code. There is a line in your code `video_clip = VideoFileClip(video.temporary_file_path())` . Below that line add `is_nsfw = is_video_nsfw(video.temporary_file_path())` then `if is_nsfw:` `raise ValidationError('The video cannot be NSFW')`

Comment: @AliEnt  You should add this line in your answer too: `is_nsfw = is_video_nsfw(video.temporary_file_path()) then if is_nsfw: raise ValidationError('The video cannot be NSFW')`

Comment: @AliEnt I want to use this method, if it works, I will mark it as a recommended answer to such kind of problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! My dear friend @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. Stack Overflow is a place to share general answers so everyone can use it, not case-based answers. So I wrote  a function to detect NSFW videos and you have to implement it on your specific code yourself.

Comment: @AliEnt it throws me an error: `raise ValueError("saved_model_path must be the valid directory of a saved model to load.")
ValueError: saved_model_path must be the valid directory of a saved model to load.`

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. I added an edit to my answer. You have to download the model file from the link on the answer to solve the error.

Comment: @AliEnt it gives me a warning messages: `WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.`

Comment: @AliEnt When i try to upload a video it says: `    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 640, 3)`

Comment: `is_image_nsfw` is unused

Comment: *strictly* speaking, "yes", but given that the signatures of those functions are so simple and the parameter named so suggestively, I don't think _calling_ those functions is a hurdle to most reasonable readers.